# Mysql design. Two types of users, two different profiles

Tags: php, yii

I want to design a DB which will be connected to PHP Application. In the app there are two types of users: company and person. Some functionality like adding articles will be done by both so in other tables there are author_id columns. So firstly I decided to create user column.

That's easy: `id, username, password, role, active, created` where role defines whether user is person or company.

Now I want to add profile table or profile tables depends on what you'd suggest (joined with the previous table by adding `profile_id` column there).

Both roles have different fields, which are required during registration.

The easiest thing would be to create one table with all required fields for both roles, allow them `NULL` values and in the PHP app (made in Yii Framework in this case) define requirements for each role in models.

The nicest thing would be to create separate tables for both roles BUT the questions is how to connect these two tables to one table using Foreign Key? Is it even possible. I know I may omit foreign key creation then based on role choose table, and from that table choose `profile_id`.

Or maybe you have another solution to my problem.

Thanks in advance for replies.
Adrian

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediary between the page and the database to assign the user to a group that has specific privileges.  It's usually accomplished with a user-group-role design.

Comment: I don't know if I made myself clear. I need to figure out how to join users table (id, username, password, role, active, created) with user profiles tables assuming there are two different types of users having different fields required during registration here's a situation [link]http://i42.tinypic.com/5eei6x.jpg how to join it?

Comment: Like I said - an intermediary.  I don't know if PHP allows it.  It's one of the things I don't like about it - too client/server.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a table for users system info (username , pass ...), and another for users profile (firstname , birthday ...), and another for groups(superuser , ...).

where user table can have multiple groups: user:one->group:many

user can have one profile user:one->profile:one

I think this is a decent solution.